# 4:1 Balun question

Tags: antenna, wire-antenna, dipole, balun

With an OCF dipole, does it matter which leg, short or long, is connected to which side of the 4:1 balun, hot(coax center) or shield?  How can you tell which is which, the balun is not marked.  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: What kind of 4:1 balun is it? Does it have two cores?

Comment: I don’t know. It’s a Radio Works  balun and completely  sealed. About 3” Dia  and 4” tall.

Comment: I saw your post and wonder what your experience has been with the OFCD as I have the same question about which wire goes where but seems it does not matter. Any more thoughts about this? Thanks Steve

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't matter. If you change the connection of the OCF dipole nothing will change from the current and voltage flow or distribution points of view.

Answer (score 1):

### Phase

The only difference will be the RF phase.   A "balun" is a transformer that goes between balanced and unbalanced sources and sinks of energy.

Unless you are trying to use two dipoles as an array, the phase doesn't matter.